# load data from s3 statement loads a single row only

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

I create and convert a Pandas dataframe into a csv using such a code:

```
main_columns = ['id', 'ticket_id', 'created_at', 'author_id', 'via_channel']

main = pd.DataFrame(columns=audits_main_columns)

for i in x:
    ..........
    main = pd.concat([main, selected_data], ignore_index=True)
    ...........

main_csv = main.to_csv(index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Then I upload the csv file to S3. Next, I use a load statement to load data into my MySQL database. However, instead of all rows, only one row is loaded.

```
LOAD DATA FROM S3 's3://{s3_bucket_name}/{s3_key}'
                    REPLACE
                    INTO TABLE {schema_name}.stg_my_table
                    CHARACTER SET latin1
                    FIELDS 
                        TERMINATED BY ','
                        ENCLOSED BY '"'
                    IGNORE 1 LINES
                    (id, ticket_id, created_at, author_id, via_channel, via_source_rel, via_source_from_deleted, via_source_from_title, 
                    via_source_from_id, via_source_to_name, via_source_to_address, metadata_suspension_type_id)
                    SET dl_load_date = current_timestamp
```

The s3 key is correct. I have verified from the logs. If I download the file manually, I can see all rows.

The order of the column also matches the csv order.

What else could I be possibly missing?

Edit:

When I print the main_csv object with the repr() function, this is how the rows look:

```
\n16972401323933,4027047,"2024-02-23T00:29:17Z",373312668598,"","","","","","","",""\n16972473479197,4027047,"2024-02-23T00:29:17Z",-1,"","","","","","","",""\n16972473537949,4027047,"2024-02-23T00:29:18Z",385177985678,"","","","","","","",""\n16975881806365,4027203,"2024-02-23T03:30:28Z",-1,"","","","","","","",""\n16975937616797,4027203,"2024-02-23T03:30:28Z",373312668598,"","","","","","","",""\n16975949119005,4027203,"2024-02-
```

Yes, only the first 4 columns are filled while the remaining columns are empty/null for now.

I also tried adding the LINES TERMINATED BY but in this case, it loads zero rows into the database instead of 1.

```
FIELDS 
   TERMINATED BY ','
   ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES 
   TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
   IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Comment: You don't have a region on the S3 uri.  Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Maybe there is another bucket of the same name in the default region that actually does contain only one row, and it is using that bucket instead of the intended bucket in another region.  Granted, this seems unlikely.

Comment: My guess is that the lines in the file are separated by `\r\n` but LOAD DATA is expecting them to be separated by `\n` by default. But you haven't shown any of the data file, so this is only a guess.

Comment: @BillKarwin Is there a way to post file content here that would accurately represent `\n` vs `\r\n` line endings?

Comment: As an experiment, you could replace the file with one that just has `\n` endings to confirm whether that is the problem.

Comment: The original file line breaks are probably fixed by posting it in Stack Overflow format, or by posting the CSV in Google Drive. I'd inspect the original file with `od` or `vi -b`, but that's a Linux/MacOS solution. I have no idea if there is an equivalent tool on Windows. I gave up on Windows about 17 years ago.

Comment: FYI bucket names are globally unique.

Comment: I have edited the qs with the repr() print output. I see the \n are at the beginning. Not sure if this is how it's meant to be. If not, Idk what I have done wrong while creating the csv to cause this in the first place. @BillKarwin

Comment: Okay, it was worth checking. I don't have an idea about what's going wrong. I suggest you contact AWS support.